# How to get many numbers of random records from database?

Tags: python, django

I know this question has been asked many times, but most of the answers use this method : `MyModel.objects.order_by('?')[:4]` which will kill the database in the second day of production.

I'm looking for a faster and lightweight solution, I'm using the one below for now, but I would like to get more than 1 random query (4 for example).

**views.py**

```
last = MyModel.objects.count() - 1
random_int = random.randint(0, last)
records = MyModel.objects.all()[random_int] #one record only
```

Any solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you need a reasonable number of elements (such as 4), I'd sample based on the queryset index rather than the id. The drawback is that you need 4 queries instead of 1, but this way you get a consistent performance that doesn't depend on the number and size of gaps in between your primary key values.

```
count = MyModel.objects.count()
sample =  random.sample(range(count), 4)
records = [MyModel.objects.all()[i] for i in sample]
```

Indexing a queryset uses `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`, so the indexing is based on the number of rows in the database, not on the id.

Comment: @Lindow I updated my answer to remove the `- 1` on count, since `range` omits the endpoint.

Comment: Yes ! I also took it away after seeing that a record was never showing, I'd even change the 'last' variable so it's even more clear for references.

Answer (score 2):

Use in keyword and generate random sample of numbers

```
random_num_sample =  random.sample(range(0, last), 4)
records = MyModel.objects.filter(id__in=random_num_sample)
```

If the database gets frequent deletes than this solution is not viable, 
If deletes are not moderate you can still use following by randomizing sample with more than 4 elements

Comment: There's no guarantee that this will actually return 4 items, unless all id values are sequential without any gaps, i.e. no items are ever deleted.

Comment: @knbk that is unfortunately truth

Comment: @iklinac The problem is that it is not sure that it'll return only 4 exact values if some are deleted, is there way to check if the record exists ?

Comment: @Lindow your return value is queryset so if you take more than 4 elements for instance 8 if your database is not moderately deleted. You can random 4 between ones you pulled, let me explain: for instance you are pulling 8 but you get only 5 then you can do random.choice to pick 4 out that 5 which would give you random sample of 4 elements

Comment: @iklinac I'm writing something where I check wether if record exists or not and will choose a new random number replacing the one missing

Comment: @Lindow this is one query, and you can see which elements you got back. What you are suggesting would create more queries to the database than this approach. It would definitely be less efficient one in my opinion.

Comment: @iklinac What you suggested is interesting, but the problem is that depending on the user there can be 8 datas or more than 90 different records, so on a user with 8 data, you're more likely to get less than 4 queries

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150618/discussion-between-iklinac-and-lindow).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in) keyword.

```
random_num = [random.randint(0, last) for i in range(4)]
```

Then use

```
queryset_obj = MyModel.objects.filter(id__in=random_num)
```

Comment: This doesn't necessarily produce list of unique random numbers

Comment: There will be less chance of collision but yeah you are right.

Comment: @ArpitSolanki Having multiple same value isn't problem in my app, but the problem is that when you filter the models you get something like this `<queryset<A><B>>` for `filter([A, B, B, A])`.

Comment: You have to use a logic to generate District random values till you get 4 District numbers. It will be little lengthy. Using sample as mentioned in another answer is a choice but it might break with less numbers. Custom logic will be most robust